# Javascript - find an element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension and trying to access the element and print it out to the console.log()

```
<li id="ember7026" class="ember-view c-tab__list__item publicConversation" data-test-id="public-conversation" data-count="1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="is_new_flag">NEW</span>Public
</li>
```

At this point I'm trying to access data-count, however didn't manage to find a way.

I have accessed the whole list by:

```
var x = document.querySelector("#ember7026")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original question: "Javascript - find an element"

So it seems like you have already found the element and have a reference to it, and now what you're looking to do is to get a certain attribute from the element reference that you have

To do so simply use the `getAttribute` function, like

```
myReferenceToHTMLNode.getAttribute("data-count")
```

Although I may have misunderstood the question, it's also possible that you're trying to find all elements with a certain attribute (in this case, data attribute) value instead of relying on the individual id.

In that case you can simply do something like

```
document.querySelector('li[data-count="1"]')
```

To print a JavaScript value to console, simply call `console.log` on the Javascript value you want to print, so for example

```
console.log(ember7026.getAttribute("data-count"))
```

Comment: Or, the `dataset` API. You could also use `myReferenceToHTMLNode.dataset.count`. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @enhzflep what is the support for dataset?

Comment: @bluejayke It says what the support is at the bottom of that link.

Comment: @daedalus I'm not asking in order to gain information, I'm asking a retorical question in response to the notion that i should have included dataset in the answer

Comment: @daedalus ok cool, but some people still want to support IE 8 etc

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I want to get that number from the "data-count", and print it out to the console.

Comment: @mmmmxex see edit

Comment: @bluejayke  it seems that the last method is working pretty fine. However, each website has a different ember****, how can I detect that?

Comment: It looks like that "class="ember-view c-tab__list__item publicConversation"" doesn't change after opening a different page.

Comment: @mmmmxex that seems like a separate issue, your want to select all of the elements with that class do `docunent.getElementsByClassName("ember-view c-tab__list__item publicConversation")` if it's the same class for all

Comment: @bluejayke - Don't forget, IE8 market share was down to 0.3%, about 3 years ago. That's just 1 user in every 333

Comment: @enhzflep but the fact that there still is a market means it's still active at least a little, 1 in 333 is a lot of you consider the billions (or at least tens of millions) of potential, total users. 1/333 * 1000000 =~ 3003, times that by at least a few dozen, or hundred etc, still something

Answer (score 1):

You can use`dataset` API to get the `test-id`.

> [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```js
const element =  document.getElementById("ember7026");
const data = element.dataset;

console.log("The ID:", data.testId);
console.log("Count:", data.count);
```

```html
<li id="ember7026" class="ember-view c-tab__list__item publicConversation" data-test-id="public-conversation" data-count="1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false"><span class="is_new_flag">NEW</span>Public
```